# How do I compile a LaTeX table exported from R?

Tags: latex

I'm completely new to LaTeX and have the MacTeX 2009 package installed, with the intent of having tables from R output into LaTeX and formatted as PDF.

I get the following LaTeX code (below) when I run an example in R (it renders ok in R, but I´d like to use TeXshop). However, when I paste this into a TeXshop window, I get the following error:

> ./Untitled.tex:2: LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined

I´m sure there is something very basic I´m missing here.

```
% latex.default(cstats, title = title, caption = caption, rowlabel = rowlabel,
%               col.just = col.just, numeric.dollar = FALSE, insert.bottom = legend,
%               rowname = lab, dcolumn = dcolumn, extracolheads = extracolheads,
%               extracolsize = Nsize, ...) 
%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
 \caption{Descriptive Statistics by treatment\label{f}} 
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{lccc}\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Drug}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Placebo}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Statistic}\tabularnewline

&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=263$}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=237$}}&\tabularnewline
\hline
age&{\scriptsize 46.5~}{49.9 }{\scriptsize 53.2} &{\scriptsize 46.7~}{50.0 }{\scriptsize 53.4} &$ F_{1,498}=0.1 ,~ P=0.754 ^{1} $\tabularnewline
sex~:~m&47\%~{\scriptsize~(123)}&44\%~{\scriptsize~(104)}&$ \chi^{2}_{1}=0.42 ,~ P=0.517 ^{2} $\tabularnewline
Primary~Symptoms~:~Depressed&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$\tabularnewline
~~~~Headache&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$\tabularnewline
~~~~Hangnail&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$\tabularnewline
~~~~Muscle~Ache&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$\tabularnewline
~~~~Stomach~Ache&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\noindent
   {\scriptsize $a$\ }{$b$\ }{\scriptsize $c$\ } represent the lower quartile $a$,
   the median $b$, and the upper quartile $c$\ for continuous variables.\\
   Numbers after percents are frequencies.\\\indent Tests used:\\
  \textsuperscript{\normalfont 1}Wilcoxon test; \textsuperscript{\normalfont 2}Pearson test
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You need some boilerplate around this to set up the document -- the LaTeXTemplate in TexShop should do.
- Your `\begin{table}` is commented out with a preceding `%`
- There are some missing backslashes in the legend text -- possibly these are just cut & paste artefacts?

This thrown-together version works for me, though you may need to tweak it for your purposes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!tbp]
\caption{Descriptive Statistics by treatment\label{f}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Drug}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Placebo}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test Statistic}
\tabularnewline
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=263$}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\scriptsize $N=237$}}&
\tabularnewline
\hline
age&{\scriptsize 46.5~}{49.9 }{\scriptsize 53.2} &{\scriptsize 46.7~}{50.0 }{\scriptsize 53.4} &$ F_{1,498}=0.1 ,~ P=0.754 ^{1}$
\tabularnewline
sex~:~m&47\%~{\scriptsize~(123)}&44\%~{\scriptsize~(104)}&$ \chi^{2}_{1}=0.42 ,~ P=0.517 ^{2} $
\tabularnewline
Primary~Symptoms~:~Depressed&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$
\tabularnewline
~~~~Headache&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$
\tabularnewline
~~~~Hangnail&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$
\tabularnewline
~~~~Muscle~Ache&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$
\tabularnewline
~~~~Stomach~Ache&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&0\%~{\scriptsize~(0)}&$^{2}$
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\noindent {\scriptsize $a$\ }{$b$\ }{\scriptsize $c$\ } represent the lower quartile $a$, the median $b$, and the upper quartile $c$ for continuous variables.\\
Numbers after percents are frequencies.\\
\indent Tests used:\\
\textsuperscript{\normalfont 1}Wilcoxon test;
\textsuperscript{\normalfont 2}Pearson test

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the package stargazer (available on CRAN), you can use the argument out="filename.tex" to output the LaTeX code directly into a Tex document. That document should then be easy to compile.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may not have a document class defined, or you are not using a document class that defines the table environment.